# What's the best way to compute when a repeated sum equals a value?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out how many draws it would take in a queen of hearts raffle until the chances of the house still having the money = 50%. I realized the way this could be solved is by doing `1/54 + 1/53... + 1/x = 0.5` but I don't know of a way to solve this without doing it manually. What are ways one can solve this without computing it all by hand?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That won't work because one does not know in advance what the term is just before the final $1/x$ on the left side. Yes it is $1/(x-1)$ but that depends on $x.$

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{53}+\frac{1}{52}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x}$ and not $\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{53}\frac{53}{54}+\frac{1}{52}\frac{52}{53}\frac{53}{54}+\cdots+\frac{1}{x}\frac{x}{x+1}\cdots\frac{52}{53}\frac{53}{54}$?  If the latter is correct then there is an obvious shortcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to compute $k$ for

$$0.5=S_k =\frac{1}{54} + \frac{1}{53} + \cdots \frac{1}{k}=H_{54}-H_{k-1}
$$

where $H_n$ is the $n-$[harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Partial_sums). This can solved numerically. Or, using the approximation $H_n \approx \log(n) +\gamma$ we get

$$ 0.5 = \log(54)-\log(k-1) \implies k = 1 + 54 \, e^{-1/2} = 33.7 $$

However, you computation seems wrong. The probabilty of getting a particular card when picking $n$ cards from a deck of $54$ cards is simply $n/54$

If you instead want the expected numbers of cards taken until the card appears, that's

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{54} i \, p_i = \frac{1}{54}\sum {i} =\frac{54 \times 55 }{54 \times 2}=27.5$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm pretty sure my computation in this context is right. In this game each week the house picks someone's guess as to where the queen of hearts is and then flips over that card. So on the first week it is 1/54, because all the cards are there. And then the second week it's 1/53 because one has already been flipped over, and it goes on. I was looking for at what week would the overall probability of the game still going be 50%.

Comment: @Alex.  So do you think the probability of picking the Queen of Hearts in the first $54$ attempts is $\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{53}+\frac{1}{52}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1} \approx 4.6$? Surely the answer should be $1 = \frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{54}+\cdots+\frac{1}{54}+\frac{1}{54}$

Comment: @Alex "And then the second week it's $1/53$" But you can't sum the probabilities in that way. $1/53$ is the _conditional probability_ of guessing in the second week given that we haven't guessed in the first week. Your computation _is_ wrong (and Henry's comments are right). The probability of guessing the card in the second week is the same as guessing in the first week.